# Use static function from a class without naming the class

Tags: c#, function, class, namespaces

How can I access functions from a class without having to name that class every time? I know how to use "using" so that I don't have to name the namespace but I was hoping there was a way to do with this static functions so that I can call them the way I would call a function in the same class.

Comment: Why would you think that would work? What does the compiler do when you have two static methods with the same name and signature?

Comment: Couldn't the same thing happen with two namespaces? I imagined if there were a conflict the compiler would let me know.

Comment: This feature is tentatively planned for the [next version of C#](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Home); you'll be able to say `using System.Console;` and then just `Write(...)`.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Why anybody would think that? Because classes are (among other things) namespaces, and there is no reason that there are things you can do with simple namespaces (like `using` them) that you cannot do with classes.

Answer (score 15):

using static yournamespace.yourclassname;

then call the static class method without class name;

Example:

Class1.cs

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Utils
    {
        public static void Hello()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static WindowsFormsApplication1.Utils;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Hello();    // <====== LOOK HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer! Thanks.
You could improve it with a code sample.

Comment: Could you please clarify this to specify that this is only possible in C# 6 or later? The question is very old, so maybe the asker does not have the possibility to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

In C#? Not possible. Because it's a  full OOP programming language and it was designed to work with objects you can't use functions outside the scope of an object. When calling static methods you have to specify the class where that static method lives...

```
Class.StaticMethod();
```

you can only use the short-hand notation if this method is call from within the same class...

```
StaticMethod();
```

But remember that you will not get access to instance members because static methods donot belong to instance of an object

### Update based on comment

Looks like it will be possible to call static members without having to specify the class that declares it in C# 6, and you will be able to reference classes directly in `using` statements...in similar fashion to Java...[more info here](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: But you can surely use them without an object, if they are static.

Comment: outside the scope of the class? Not in c# mate

Comment: Where exactly is your object in Class.StaticMethod()? Remember, it could be called like `static Class() { StaticMethod(); }`. No object involved.

Comment: what on earth are you talking about? `Class.StaticMethod()` is NOT an object, it's a statement, a method call

Comment: @PeterSchneider mate you are completely off the context, have you actually read the answer you are commenting?

Comment: "Not possible" and marked as "done" for [C# 6.0](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Home) don't exactly align. "Not possible in C# up to 5.0" would be ok answer, random mentioning of "full OOP language" as reason for this historical design decision is not...

Comment: I was thinking that you meant "class", not "object". Static functions are generally not connected to "normal" objects. The OP mentioned static functions and I assumed he was just tired of prefixing them with a class name.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov interesting indeed, I wasn't aware of the new features of c# 6...it actually remind me of using `import` statements in `Java`. However, it looks like a step backwards in the evolution of the c# language considering that years ago they were promoting stuff like removing multiple inheritance to avoid name collisions, however, this seems to bring back some possible name collisions since you can't guarantee that 2 different classes expose members with the same signature

Answer (score 1):

I routinely have

```
static Action<object> o = s => Console.WriteLine(s);
```

in my code which makes debug output so much less noisy. That way I can call Console's static Writeline() much easier. Would that help?

Comment: -1 this is not a static method, this is actually a delegate. Furthermore, you will not be able to access this from outside the class where the delegate is defined

Comment: I was trying to show that you can call the static method Console.Writeline() without mentioning Console each time. You call it with `o("Hello World");`.

Comment: You could simplify this to `static Action<object> o = Console.WriteLine;`

Comment: @hypehuman Interesting, thanks! I cannot test it right now but if you are sure feel free to add it to the post.

Comment: Or even  maybe `static Action<object> o => Console.WriteLine;` would be better. My guess is that the compiler might end up inlining that call.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to define a globally-scoped procedure then the short answer is no, you can't do this in c#.  No global functions, procedures or objects.

In C# everything apart from namespaces and types (class, struct, enum, interface) must be defined inside a type.  Static members (fields, properties and methods) can be used without an instance of the class, but only by referencing the type that owns them.  Non-static members need an instance of the owning class.

This is fundamental to the syntax of the language.  C# is neither C nor C++, where you *can* define global objects, functions and procedures.